# I have problem in sketch compiling error message is 'printNormalModeMessage' is not declared so what I can do

Tags: arduino-uno

```cpp
/* a,rduino door look project */
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define RST_PIN  9
#define SS_PIN 10

byte readCard[4];
char* myTags[100] = {};
int tagsCount = 0;
String tagID = "";
boolean successRead = false;
boolean correctTag = false;
int proximitySensor;
boolean doorOpened = false;

//Creat instance
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
//Parameters : (rs, enable, d4, d5, d6, d7)
Servo myServo;

void setup() {
  //Initiating
  SPI.begin();
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  myServo.attach(8);

  myServo.write(10);

  lcd.print("-No Master Tag!-");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("   SCAN NOW");

  while (!successRead) {
    successRead = getID();
    if (successRead == true) {
      myTags[tagsCount] = strdup(tagID.c_str());
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("-Master  Tag Set!-");
      tagsCount++;
    }
  }
  successRead = false;
  printNormalModeMessage();
}
void loop() {
  int proximitySensor = analogRead(A0);
  // if door closed
  if (proximitySensor > 200) {
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
      return;
    }
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      return;
    } 
    tagID = "";
    for ( unit8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      readCard[i]  = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
      tagID.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i],HEX));
    }
    tagID.toUpperCase();
    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();

    correctTag = false;
    if (tagID == myTags[0]) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Program mode:");
      lcd.setCursor (1,0);
      lcd.print("Add/ Remove Tag");
      while (!successRead) {
        successRead = getID();
        if (successRead == true) {
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (tagID == myTags[i]) {
              myTags[i] = "";
              lcd.clear();
              lcd.setCursor(0,0);
              lcd.print("   Tag Removed!");
              printNormalModwMessage();
              tagsCount++;
              return:
            }
          }
        myTags[tagsCount] = strdup(tagID.c_str());
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print(" Tag Added!");
        printNormalModeMessage();
        return;
        }
      }
    }
    successRead = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      if (tagID == myTags[i] ) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print( "Access Granted!");       
        myServo.write(170);
        printNormalModeMessage();
        correctTag = true;
      }
    }
    if (correctTag == false) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(" Access Denide!");
      printNormalModeMessags();
    }
  }
  else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(" Door opeded!");
    while (!doorOpened) {
      proximitySensor = analogRead(A0); 
      if (proximitySensor > 200)  {
        doorOpened = true ;
      }
    }
    doorOpened = false;
    delay(500);
    myServo.write(10);
    printNormalModeMessage();
  }
}
uint8_t getID() {
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return 0;
  }
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
     return 0;  
  }
  tagID = "";
  for ( unit_8 i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    readCard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
    tagID.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i],HEX));
  }
  tagID.toUpperCase();
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  return 1;
}
void printNoramalModeMessage() {
  delay(1500);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("-Access Control-");
  lcd.setCorsor(0,1);
  lcd.print( " Scan Your Tag!");
}
```

```
Arduino: 1.8.2 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries -libraries D:\arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10802 -build-path C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_499902 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose D:\Arduino\dooropened.ino\dooropened.ino.ino
C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries -libraries D:\arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10802 -build-path C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_499902 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose D:\Arduino\dooropened.ino\dooropened.ino.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src\SPI.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src\MFRC522.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src\MFRC522Debug.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src\MFRC522Extended.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src\MFRC522Hack.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src\LiquidCrystal.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\avr\Servo.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\nrf52\Servo.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\sam\Servo.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\samd\Servo.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src\stm32f4\Servo.cpp" -o "nul"
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10802 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal\src" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src" "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_303473\sketch\dooropened.ino.ino.cpp.o"
D:\Arduino\dooropened.ino\dooropened.ino.ino: In function 'void setup()':

dooropened.ino:49: error: 'printNormalModeMessage' was not declared in this scope

   printNormalModeMessage();

                          ^

D:\Arduino\dooropened.ino\dooropened.ino.ino: In function 'void loop()':

dooropened.ino:62: error: 'unit8_t' was not declared in this scope

     for ( unit8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

           ^

dooropened.ino:62: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope

     for ( unit8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                          ^

dooropened.ino:84: error: 'printNormalModwMessage' was not declared in this scope

               printNormalModwMessage();

                                      ^

dooropened.ino:86: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token

               return:

                     ^

dooropened.ino:86: error: expected ';' before ':' token

dooropened.ino:86: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token

dooropened.ino:93: error: 'printNormalModeMessage' was not declared in this scope

         printNormalModeMessage();

                                ^

dooropened.ino:105: error: 'printNormalModeMessage' was not declared in this scope

         printNormalModeMessage();

                                ^

dooropened.ino:113: error: 'printNormalModeMessags' was not declared in this scope

       printNormalModeMessags();

                              ^

dooropened.ino:129: error: 'printNormalModeMessage' was not declared in this scope

     printNormalModeMessage();

                            ^

D:\Arduino\dooropened.ino\dooropened.ino.ino: In function 'uint8_t getID()':

dooropened.ino:140: error: 'unit_8' was not declared in this scope

   for ( unit_8 i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

         ^

dooropened.ino:140: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope

   for ( unit_8 i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                       ^

D:\Arduino\dooropened.ino\dooropened.ino.ino: In function 'void printNoramalModeMessage()':

dooropened.ino:152: error: 'class LiquidCrystal' has no member named 'setCorsor'

   lcd.setCorsor(0,1);

       ^

Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI 
Using library rfid-master at version 1.3.6 in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\rfid-master 
Using library LiquidCrystal at version 1.0.5 in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal 
Using library Servo at version 1.1.2 in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries\Servo 
exit status 1
'printNormalModeMessage' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You had typos in the title and you have an awful lot of typos in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
void printNoramalModeMessage() {
  delay(1500);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("-Access Control-");
  lcd.setCorsor(0,1);
  lcd.print( " Scan Your Tag!");
}
```

You can't spell "Normal".

Answer (score 0):

See :

```
dooropened.ino:49: error: 'printNormalModeMessage' was not declared in this scope
```

printNormalModeMessage();

You didn't implement this function.

(please align your code correctly to make it readable)

Comment: (it seems now the code is formatted, the function can be seen easier), See Majenko's answer